# QB PRO 2013 + Web Connector with closed company

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc, qbwc

I have Quickbooks Pro 2013 with the Web Connector installed.

I have created a sync application, granted permissions and everything, and I get the Web connector to exchange data between the company file (QB PRO 2013) and a web service successfully.

This happens only while QB PRO 2013 is **OPEN**. It doesn't require a logged in user, just keeping the application open is good enough for the Web Connector to connect to the company file and exchange data.

The thing is when I close the application the Web Connector starts complaining with a **QBWC1013** error, saying:
**Could not start QuickBooks.** - second row in this link: http://www.zoho.com/crm/help/quickbooks/troubleshooting.html#sthash.hk3Dc8dl.dpuf

I'm used to QB POS, where I don't need the company open. Is this behavior different on non POS products ? Do I need to keep QB open all the time ? The path to the company file is OK as well as the syncing logic, we are able to connect, authenticate, exchange data both ways smoothly but only while QB is open (being logged in is not necessary, just keeping the app open).

It is like the Web Connector needs a running instance of QuickBooks to authenticate, because when it does so, QuickBooks flickers like if someone were logging in and then logging out.

The Web Connector application has been granted full access and Admin login to the company file.

Any thoughts :)

Answer (score 2):

First, know that *the very first time you connect things* you have to make sure QuickBooks is open. If you haven't had QuickBooks open at all yet, make sure it's open the very first time to get things connected.

After that, QuickBooks does not have to be open, provided you have configured things correctly.

To answer your questions:

> Is this behavior different on non POS products ?

Yes. Slightly.

> Do I need to keep QB open all the time ?

No.

> The path to the company file is OK as well as the syncing logic, we are able to connect, authenticate, exchange data both ways smoothly but only while QB is open (being logged in is not necessary, just keeping the app open).

Hit F2 in QuickBooks, and make sure that the path that's shown in the dialog window that pops up is EXACTLY the path that your web service is returning to the Web Connector. It must be EXACTLY the same.

If you're still having trouble, double-check that the app is allowed to connect in the QuickBooks settings, and that a valid user is chosen in the settings, restart the computer, and try again.

If you're still having trouble, post your Web Connector logs (in VERBOSE mode: [QuickBooks Web Connector - how to set VERBOSE mode](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector#setting_the_web_connector_to_use_verbose_logging_mode)) so that we can help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Ohh, Keith, I know you back from the days of the Intuit forums.

I think the only option left is posting the logs, will try to get some logs and reply back.

Everything else is per the book.

Comment: QB has to be open the first time you connect for the authorization screen. After that it can be closed.